# How can I locally create nodes for Cassandra using Django Framework on PyCharm?

Tags: django, cassandra, pycharm

I decided to change my database to Cassandra because the website I am creating has very large dataset and currently postgres has extensive query times. From my reading, Cassandra would greatly improve scalability.

However, I am not sure how to create a multinode cluster to run locally on my machine for my databases info in settings.py.

I was wondering if anyone can give me directions on how to create "multiple hosts" for my settings.py file using Pycharm?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Django framework, so I cannot really answer your question in detail. But if I get you right, you want to start all Cassandra nodes in the same machine. This might be okay during development, but in production it wouldn't perform well, probably it wouldn't be significantly faster than a postgres database using the same data structures. To benefit from the scaling possibilities of Cassandra you have to run it on a cluster of machines.

Comment: Thank you Matthias. I was trying to do this primarily for the development phase.